# Assigning a new user to the movie in the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, automapper

I wrote an application that works as follows:

1. User create account and log in.
2. User paste link to the film from the Filmweb.pl database in the appropriate field.
3. The application parses the link and the received results such as: directing, description, cover etc. are added to the application database.
4. And so on: user can paste a link to another film (and if the title has not been added before), the parsing process will repeat.

What I described above works, but not as I want. Suppose I have users named Jarek and Damian. Each of them will paste a movie with the same title into the parser, eg. "Obecność" (eng. "The Conjuring"). Currently, in the database will happen something like this:

[image: http://funkyimg.com/i/2Dnfd.jpg]

but I would like to have something like that:
[image: http://funkyimg.com/i/2DnfR.jpg]

because it makes no sense to repeat all the data concerning the film, since they are the same, just add a new user to the field UserName assigned to a specific film. The only question is how to do it?

**The whole code of my application is available here:** https://bitbucket.org/DamianOS_MP5/filmwebparser-old-version

I read somewhere that I need to create a many-to-many relationship. I add a property to the `Film` class:

```
public List<FilmUser> FilmUserList { get; set; }
```

and to the `FilmUser` class property and constructor:

```
public List<Film> FilmList { get; set; }

public FilmUser(string name)
{
    IdentityUser user = new IdentityUser(name);
}
```

Then I change methods, for example AddFilm from:

```
public string AddFilm(Film film)
{
    if (film.Title == null)
        return "W podanym linku nie wykryto filmu.";
    else if (!_context.Films.Any(t => t.Title == film.Title && t.UserName == film.UserName))
    {
        _context.Add(film);
        return string.Empty;
    }
    else
        return "Podany film znajduje się już w bazie.";
}
```

to:

```
public string AddFilm(Film film)
{
    if (film.Title == null)
        return "W podanym linku nie wykryto filmu.";
    else if (!_context.Films.Any(t => t.Title == film.Title))
    {
        film.FilmUserList.Add(new FilmUser(film.UserName));
        _context.Add(film);
        return string.Empty;
    }
    else
    {
        if (!_context.Films.Any(t => t.FilmUserList.Contains(new FilmUser(film.UserName))))
        {
            film.FilmUserList.Add(new FilmUser(film.UserName));
            _context.Update(film);
            return string.Empty;
        }
        else
            return "Podany film znajduje się już w bazie.";
    }
}
```

So the next step is to create a new migration. And here is the error:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation
>   property 'Film.FilmUserList' of type 'List'. Either manually
>   configure the relationship, or ignore this property from the model.

Using the example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#many-to-many I wrote:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<Film>()
        .HasKey(s => new { s.??? });
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
}
```

but what to put in place of question marks? I made a mistake somewhere, but I don't know where. I write about it in details, because I am trying to understand it.

Comment: in your entity I think you could use `ICollection` which EF understands- that you use `List` in your program is another story.

Comment: Changing to `ICollection` didn't bring results :(

Comment: you surely must have gotten another error message?

Comment: No. I changed `List` to `ICollection` and had same error. Is that what I had to do?

Comment: So you get the error message `Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Film.FilmUserList' of type 'List'.` even if you are not using a `List`? Could you add an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with that behavior?

Comment: [...] of type 'ICollection' [...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not remove username from the film table. Instead, create a seperate link table between the user and the film table looking something like:

UserFilm

```
user_id | film_id
    1   |   203
    3   |   203
    3   |   208
    1   |   209
```

This way any user can have many films and a 2 users can share the same film. This is what's needed in terms of your SQL database to support the sort of code you mention and the many to many relationships.

I'm happy to take a look at your code at lunch if you like the look of this solution. Though im sure others will assist you further before then.

Good luck

Comment: I don't think that's the OPs problem - he's trying to create a migration which fails. Entity Framework can do the joining table for him. He shouldn't do that manually

Comment: I removed `UserName` property from `Film` class. I created the `UserFilm` class, changed `OnModelCreating` method and added a migration. But now I can't register new user, because Username is always null here:  `var user = new FilmUser() { Email = vm.Email };`. How (and where) to bind (create) new `UserFilm` object with data?

Comment: var filmUse = new FilmUser() { Email = vm.Email, UserId = vm.UserId };

You need to provide the user id when creating a filmuser

Comment: But I don't have property `UserId` in my `RegisterViewModel` class. I can't get Id from user in registration form

Comment: On register, first create the user. Then create the FilmUser entries as you'll have an ID to work with.

Comment: I did it in a different way, but [it works](http://funkyimg.com/i/2DDTg.jpg). Thanks for help (table with example) :D